# How to hide DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html document which has the following structure (which I cannot change):

```
<h2>...</h2>
<div>..</div>
<div..<//div>
.../...
<h2>...</h2>
<div>..</div>
<div..<//div>
.../...
repeating
```

I have create the following code which successfully hides the h2 element based on the text taken from a field called searchTarget:

```
<script>
function toggle_targets() {
        var searchValue = document.getElementById("searchTarget").value;
        var headers = document.getElementsByTagName('h2');
        for (i=0; i<headers.length; i++) {
                if (headers[i].textContent.includes(searchValue)) {
                        headers[i].style.display = "none";
                } else {
                        headers[i].style.display = "block";
                }
        }
}
</script>
```

This successfully hides the header elements, but I want also the code to hide the next two  elements just underneath the header if the header is hidden.

Comment: What do you mean with "_which I cannot change_"? If you can access and change JS, you've free hands to do any changes in the DOM too. Anyway, there's [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling), you can use that to target the next two elements.

Comment: I think OP is saying that they can't change the source of the HTML document itself, instead of manipulating the DOM.

Comment: Try using `nextSibling()` and `tagName()` functions to look at the elements immediately after the `h2` one.

Comment: @ATD `nextSibling` considers also textnodes as siblings, and that's usually something you want to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JavasScript Siblings](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-siblings/)

[nextsibling](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nextsibling.asp)

```
function toggle_targets() {

        var searchValue = document.getElementById("searchTarget").value;
        var headers = document.getElementsByTagName('h2');
        for (i=0; i<headers.length; i++) {
                if (headers[i].textContent.includes(searchValue)) {
                        headers[i].style.display = "none";
                        headers[i].nextSibling.nextSibling.style.display = "none";
                        headers[i].nextSibling.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                        headers[i].style.display = "block";
                        headers[i].nextSibling.nextSibling.style.display = "block";
                        headers[i].nextSibling.style.display = "block";
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: That assumes that the structure only has two `div` elements after each `h2`.  I think the implication is that there could be any number of them.  Perhaps a `while` loop testing for `tagName()` values for each sibling would be required?

Comment: @ATD  `also the code to hide the next two elements`   My code does exactly what is asked if Im not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with `nextElementSibling` to get the element's sibling as DOM element. This code hides the next two siblings of the selected `h2` element. It does not matter which element a sibling is (`input`, `div`, ....).

```
function toggle_targets() {
        var searchValue = document.getElementById("searchTarget").value;
        var headers = document.getElementsByTagName('h2');
        for (i=0; i<headers.length; i++) {
                if (headers[i].textContent.includes(searchValue)) {
                        headers[i].style.display = "none";
                        headers[i].nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.style.display = "none";
                        headers[i].nextElementSibling.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                        headers[i].style.display = "block";
                        headers[i].nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
                        headers[i].nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
                }
        }
}
```

**Edit:**  Added code example.

```js
function toggle_targets() {
        var searchValue = "Hide me!";
        var headers = document.getElementsByTagName('h2');
        for (i=0; i<headers.length; i++) {
                if (headers[i].textContent.includes(searchValue)) {
                        headers[i].style.display = "none";
                        headers[i].nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.style.display = "none";
                        headers[i].nextElementSibling.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                        headers[i].style.display = "block";
                        headers[i].nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
                        headers[i].nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
                }
        }
}
```

```html
<h2 onclick="toggle_targets()">Hide me! (on click)</h2>
<div>D1</div>
<div>D2</div>
<h2 >Headline 2</h2>
<div>D3</div>
<div>D4</div>
<h2 >Headline 3</h2>
<div>D5</div>
<div>D6</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```js
function toggle_targets() {
  const search = document.getElementById("searchTarget");

  for (const header of document.getElementsByTagName("h2")) {
    const content = header.textContent || '';
    const includeSearchText = content.includes(search.value)

    const next1 = header.nextElementSibling;
    const next2 = next1.nextElementSibling;

    for (const el of [header, next1, next2]) {
      if (!el) return

      el.style.display = includeSearchText ? 'none' : 'display'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, so much, I will try also your solution, I this all are working

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern is regular, i.e. it's always a H2 and two divs, you could use an adjacent sibling combinator to select all the elements, and then iterate through the found elements and hide the ones you need:

```js
const searchValue = 'header',
  hiddens = document.querySelectorAll('h2, h2 + div, h2 + div + div');
for (let n = 0, eN = hiddens.length; n < eN; n++) {
  if (n % 3 === 0 && hiddens[n].textContent.includes(searchValue) === false) {
    n += 2; // No keyword in this header, jump to the next header
    continue;
  }
  hiddens[n].style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<h2>Hidden header 1</h2>
<div>Hidden div 1</div>
<div>Hidden div 2</div>
<div>Visible div 3</div>
<div>Visible div 4</div>
<h2>Head element 2</h2>
<div>Visible Head div 5</div>
<div>Visible header div 6</div>
<div>Visible div 7</div>
<div>Visible div 8</div>
<h2>Yet another header 3</h2>
<div>Hidden div 9</div>
<div>Hidden div 10</div>
<div>Visible div 11</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is useful, I will try also your solution